# JavaFX detect button clicks with less code

Tags: java, javafx

Im creating a lot of buttons in JavaFX, I'm trying to make the code shorter. I tried using a switch statement but sadly no result as I got an error: `constant expression required`

```
Object source = e.getSource();
    switch (source) {
        case equals(leftPerent):
            appendText("(");
        default:
            break;
}
```

My current working code is just writing tons of if statements, is it possible to shorten it?

```
@FXML
private Button num1, num2, num3;

public void onNumberButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(num1)) {
        appendText("1");
    }
    if (e.getSource().equals(num2)) {
        appendText("2");
    }
    if (e.getSource().equals(num3)) {
        appendText("3");
    }
}
```

FXML File:

```
<Button text="1" fx:id="num1" onAction="#onNumberButtonClick" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="CENTER"></Button>
<Button text="2" fx:id="num2" onAction="#onNumberButtonClick" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"></Button>
<Button text="3" fx:id="num3" onAction="#onNumberButtonClick" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0"></Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will work as I'm unfamiliar with FXML and whether an FXML ID is the same as a programmatically assigned id.

```
public void onButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        Button button = (Button) e.getSource();
        String id = button.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case "num1": {
                appendText("1");
            }break;
            {.. etc ?..}
        }
    }
```

When doing this, programmatically, I typically end up with:

```
Button one = new Button();
one.setOnAction(e->{appendText("1");});
```

but again, I don't know if assigning an event handler programmatically will break any FXML stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using something like this `switch` statement like this. Only use the same event handler for functionality that is sufficiently similar. Otherwise it's better to use different event handlers.

In this case the functionality is similar enough. I recommend avoiding using the `switch` nonetheless. A good way of doing this is attaching some data to the source. Usually you'd use the `userData` property or the `properties` map, but in this case you don't need that, since the info is available via the `text` property:

```
@FXML
private void onNumberButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
    Button source = (Button) e.getSource();
    appendText(source.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
Public void onNumberButtonClick(actionevent e) {
    Button b = (button) e. Getsource() ;
    AppentText(b.gettext());
}
```

Comment: The only issue I'd have with this is it'd be hard to maintain as the presentation is being used as the data. But if it's just a one-off program that will become vaporware before long, it'd be the quickest way to do it and a good time-saver.

Comment: I totally agree if it's not a 1:1 of button to append value. Or if the button click has to fire a feature of some other "service". In that case I'd use an enum/provider so that edits are limited to fxml and provider.